# Fixed width font for entering code in markdown

Tags: bug, design, ui

I'm just in the process of creating a new question and I noticed the font in the markdown window isn't fixed width. Did the font used to be fixed width before the branding?

Example from a random question:

[image]

Personally, this makes it a bit more difficult to get code lining up in the markdown window. Once the markdown is rendered as HTML the preformatted code blocks come out fixed width. Trying to coordinate things between the two areas becomes a bit more difficult.

Can we get a fixed width font for the markdown entry area?

The font-family settings for textarea from StackOverflow would be fine (and familiar) for markup entry.

---

As a temporary fix I've created a Stylebot style for salesforce.stackexchange.com [Salesforce StackExchange Markdown Fixed Width](http://stylebot.me/styles/7683)

It forces the textarea used to enter Markdown to use a fixed width font.

Comment: It was definitely fixed-width before, and should be again. Asterixes in particular don't look great in the edit window with the new font (especially at high resolutions).